# Is there a way to filter issues in GitLab by whether or not they have a related merge request?

Tags: gitlab

I have a number of issues assigned to me to work on, and I've made merge requests to fix many of them. I am looking for a query that would let me filter out issues with a related merge request.

The GitLab instance I'm using is at v14.4.2.

I've looked in the docs for both [basic search](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/) and [advanced search](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/advanced_search.html), but can't figure out a good query for this.

The equivalent query in GitHub would be `is:issue is:open assignee:legowerewolf -linked:pr`

Comment: You can trivially find all issues and MRs created by you, then subtract the set of MRs from the set of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of writing, that's not possible.

Generally, if a feature is not listed in the docs, then it hasn't been implemented. You can search for and existing feature request in the [GitLab issue tracker](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues) (though I didn't find one) or file a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Arty-chan above, there's no built-in way to do this. After futzing around in PowerShell and with the API for a bit, I came up with this:

```
$GitlabToken = '[your GitLab PAT with API read access]'
$APIRoot = 'https://[your GitLab server here]/api/v4'

$TokenHeader = @{
    "PRIVATE-TOKEN" = $GitlabToken
}

$User = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "$APIRoot/user" -Headers $TokenHeader

$UserOpenIssues = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "$APIRoot/issues" -Headers $TokenHeader -Body @{
    assignee_id = $User.id
    state       = "opened"
    scope       = "all"
}

foreach ($Issue in $UserOpenIssues) {
    $Issue | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "related_merge_requests" -Value (
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "$APIRoot/projects/$($Issue.project_id)/issues/$($Issue.iid)/related_merge_requests" -Headers $TokenHeader | Where-Object { $_.state -eq "opened" }
    )
}

$UserOpenIssues = $UserOpenIssues | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = { $_.labels[0] } }

Write-Host "Open issues without a merge request assigned to $($User.name):"

$UserOpenIssues
| Where-Object { $_.related_merge_requests.Count -eq 0 }
| Format-Table -Property @(
    @{name = "Reference"; expression = { $_.references.full } }
    @{name = "Title"; expression = { $_.title } }
    @{name = "Labels"; expression = { $_.labels } }
)
```